# jQuery posting valid json in request body

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

So according to the [jQuery Ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), it serializes data in the form of a query string when sending requests, but setting `processData:false` should allow me to send actual JSON in the body.  Unfortunately I'm having a hard time determining first, if this is happening and 2nd what the object looks like that is being sent to the server.  All I know is that the server is not parsing what I'm sending.

When using [http client](http://ditchnet.org/httpclient/) to post an object literal `{someKey:'someData'}`, it works. But when using jQuery with `data: {someKey:'someData'}`, it fails.  Unfortunately when I analyze the request in Safari, it says the message payload is `[object Object]` ... great...  and in Firefox the post is blank...

When logging the body content on the Java side it literally gets `[object Object]` so how does one send REAL JSON data??

Has anyone had experience with a Java service serializing JSON data in the request body, with the request sent from jQuery?

BTW here is the full $.ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {
        "command": "on"
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        app.log("device control succeeded");
    },
    error: function(){
        app.log("Device control failed");
    },
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/devices/{device_id}/control'
});
```

Answer (score 348, accepted):

An actual JSON request would look like this:

```
data: '{"command":"on"}',
```

Where you're sending an actual JSON string.  For a more general solution, use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON#Converting_objects_into_JSON) to serialize an object to JSON, like this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ "command": "on" }),
```

To support older browsers that don't have the `JSON` object, use [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) which will add it in.

---

What's currently happening is since you have `processData: false`, it's basically sending this: `({"command":"on"}).toString()` which is `[object Object]`...what you see in your request.

Comment: so do I no longer need the processData: false using `JSON.stringify()` ?

Comment: @brad - correct, it won't matter after doing this because it's *already* a string, and in that case [jQuery won't process it further](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/ajax.js#L207).

Comment: worked like a charm, many thanks!  Is it true then that all request bodies are expected to be strings that get parsed on the other end?

Comment: Why does jQuery parse the `data` into a string, as opposed to just sending it as JSON?

Comment: Side note:  if anybody needs it as a "body request payload" instead of form data, don't forget to include `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` as mentioned in this thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201270/how-to-submit-json-data-by-request-body-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Seal them up

```
//contentType: false,
//processData: false,
```