# How to submit JSON Data by Request Body in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am not expert in jQuery, consider me fresher. Here is my code which one not responsible for jQuery JSON data submission by Request Body.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>jQuery Data submitted by JSON Body Request</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url : "/",
        type: "POST",
        data: [
            {id: 1, name: "Shahed"}, 
            {id: 2, name: "Hossain"}
        ],
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType   : "json",
        success    : function(){
            console.log("Pure jQuery Pure JS object");
        }
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Example of submission JS Object by JSON Body Request<br/>
        Its could submitted mass amount of data by Message body<br/>
        It's secured and faster than any data submission .
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Post Source appeared:

```
Shahed=undefined&Hossain=undefined
```

But desired Post Source is:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Shahed"},{"id":2,"name":"Hossain"}]
```

How do I get the desired Post Source for each Request Body?

Comment: First, you have to actually submit json data rather than an object.

Comment: If you are familiar with firebug debugger then you will see the each request in console All tab. Where you will get Post Source. Firebug console is responsible to display valid `JSON` `Request` `Body` on `Post Source`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is the right code for your desired out put.

```
$.ajax({
        url : "/",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify([
            {id: 1, name: "Shahed"}, 
            {id: 2, name: "Hossain"}
        ]),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType   : "json",
        success    : function(){
            console.log("Pure jQuery Pure JS object");
        }
    });
```

Your must convert JS Object to String and `JSON.stringify(JSObject)` is the method responsible for that.