# Using ajax in Servant

Tags: ajax, haskell, haskell-wai, servant

I use Haskell with `servant-0.7.1` fo realisation server.Below is my source code:

```
type UserRestAPI 
    = "rest" :> "users" :> Get '[JSON] [User]
    :<|> "rest" :> "user" :> ReqBody '[JSON] User :> Post '[PlainText] Text


serverUserRestAPI :: ServerT UserRestAPI AppM
serverUserRestAPI = usersGet :<|> userPost

userPost :: User -> AppM Text
userPost user = do
    newUser <- runDb $ do insert user
    liftIO $ putStrLn $ show newUser
    return $ append (toPathPiece newUser) "\r\n"
```

The model of `User`:

```
let mongoSettings = (mkPersistSettings (ConT ''MongoContext)) {mpsGeneric = False}
    in share [mkPersist mongoSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
User
    fam   String
    im    String 
    ot    String 
    email String 
    login String
    pswd  String
    deriving Show
|]

$(deriveJSON defaultOptions ''User)
```

For testin `curl` was used, as shown below.

```
curl --verbose --request POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '{"userFam": "Fam", "userIm": "Im", "userOt": "Ot", "userEmail": "mail@mail.ru", "userLogin": "test", "userPswd": "test"}' \
    http://127.0.0.1:3000/rest/user
```

Everything is working. The data added to the database.But when I use `ajax` from backend, as shown below.

```
var formElement = $("#id_form");
var formData = formElement.serializeArray();

var objectData = {};

for(var i = 0; i < formData.length; i++)
    objectData[formData[i].name] = formData[i].value;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: "/rest/user",
    dataType: "text",
    cache : false,
    contentType : "application/json",
    data: objectData,
    success: function(result){
        consoloe.log(result)
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
});
```

I get an error!

```
jquery.js:4 POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/rest/user 400 (Bad Request)
```

The debugger checked object `objectData`. All right (`Object {userFam: "qqq", userIm: "www", userOt: "eee", userEmail: "rrr", userLogin: "ttt"…}`).
I can not understand what was going on.

Comment: Have you tried with [servant-js](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-js)? It lets you generate jQuery-based functions for querying your service. Even if you don't want to use it, you might want to compare the JS code generated there with yours.

Comment: IMO your object data does not look right - see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159701/jquery-posting-valid-json-in-request-body

Comment: in short can you try this with: `dataType: "json"`, `data: JSON.stringify(objectData)` (right now you are using `.toString()` on your `objectData` this is wher ethe `Object` part comes from and this is not valid JSON)

Comment: I tried `JSON.stringify(objectData)`. Now it works!!! Thank you very much for the idea with `JSON.stringif`.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer I hope you don't mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's really a problem with your `ajax` call as you don't provide a valid JSON object but just `objectData.toString()` as `data:` - the common solution is to use `JSON.stringify`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: "/rest/user",
    dataType: "json",
    cache : false,
    data: JSON.stringify(objectData),
    success: function(result){
         // ...
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
});
```

another great example what is wrong with untyped languages ;)