# read post req in Node js

Tags: node.js

I have ajax code in below , i want to read data which is i am sending using ajax i want to read data in server side.

```
     $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                     data: {hurl: "test data"},
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    url: 'http://localhost:5000/hmap',
                    success: function(data) {
//                            console.log('success');
//                            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            });
```

below is my server side node js code

```
var hmapdata = [];
app.post('/hmap', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        db.collection("heatmap").find().toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            hmapdata = result;

            db.close();
        });
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        res.send(hmapdata);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: You req.body does contain the data you are sending from Ajax request. Use that

Comment: use the 'network' tab in dev tools to gather more info on the POST call.

Comment: But what is the problem? If you are using body -parser  middleware, everything should work

Comment: please let me know how to send and receive in server side. i am new to node js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a JSON payload using jQuery Ajax, you must send a an actual JSON string, not a javascript object.

So you would need to do:

`data: JSON.stringify({ hurl: "test data" })`

[image]

This is what you're sending:

[image]

Now in your server, if you're using the `body-parser` middleware, the posted JSON will be available in `req.body`

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/hmap', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); // req.body.hurl == "test data"
});
```

More details on: [jQuery posting valid json in request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159701/jquery-posting-valid-json-in-request-body)