# Can't get the result from the ajax calling

Tags: json, ajax, request, postman

I'm trying to get `application/json` data sets from an ajax call.
Using the same setting that I initially tested on Postman where I got the data normally from the request, I can't get the proper result that I get from Postman with my JavaScript code.

[image: It's a post request and the Content Type is application/json.]

[image: The request body's empty. Not sending any parameter.]

[image: Header information I get from the postman request.]

Following is the source I'm trying to work out.

```
$.ajax({
    url: myUrl,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success:function(res){
        alert(res);
    },
    error:function(request,status,error){
        alert(request+" : "+status+" : "+error);
    }
});
```

Execute the source above, it goes into the error part and I get the alert message like ' [object Object] : error :  '. 
[object Object] for request, error for status, and nothing for the error.

I've tried to put different settings there like async, cache, tried to put the contentType in a separated header setting like header: {"Content-Type":"appplication/json"} but none of them has worked yet.

[image: This is the failed request header on the google chrome developer tool.]

How can I make it work? Thank you ahead for helps.

Answer (score 0):

you are just sending empty Json request.
you must have some request data like :

```
data: '{"orgId":"1111"}'
```

for more info visit [jQuery posting valid json in request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159701/jquery-posting-valid-json-in-request-body)

Answer (score 0):

use the $.ajaxSetup({}); before the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want type as POST, change it to GET.
Have you tried with type as GET
I have implemented similar ajax call which works fine

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : myUrl,
    async : false,
    success : function(response) { // we have the response
        alert();
    }
    error:function(e){
        alert();
    }
});
```