# ColdFusion Form Array with comma in variable

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

Currently, there are checkboxes within a form, and the value of the selected checkboxes are stored in a DB when the form is submitted.

```
<td><input type="Checkbox" name="valueList" value="Some value, with comma"   >Some value, with comma</td> 
<td><input type="Checkbox" name="valueList" value="Another Value, with comma"   >Another value, with comma</td> 
<td><input type="Checkbox" name="valueList" value="Yet another value"   >Yet another value</td>
```

However, the issue is with the commas as the current logic uses a list to store these values. So `Some value, with comma` is inserted as `Some value` and `with comma`. The current list is created with the following:

```
<cfif isDefined("valueList")>
<cfset a=listlen(valueList)>
```

And the code continues by looping through the list. This is the only reference to `valueList` I could find in the code. Is there a way to convert this to an Array without the commas becoming an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern I use is replacing comma (,) with tilde (~) since it's not used in our domain at all, you can use any character you want.

```
<td><input type="Checkbox" name="valueList" value="Some value~ with comma"   >Some value, with comma</td> 
<td><input type="Checkbox" name="valueList" value="Another Value~ with comma"   >Another value, with comma</td> 
<td><input type="Checkbox" name="valueList" value="Yet another value"   >Yet another value</td>
```

So when the form comes over it'll be as follows:

```
form.valueList = "Some value~ with comma, Another Value~ with comma, Yet another value";
```

This is the code to get the array you want:

```
<cfscript>
  variables.myArrayList = ListToArray(form.valueList);
  for(i=1; i LTE ArrayLen(variables.myArrayList); i=i+1)
  {
    variables.myArrayList[i] = ReplaceNoCase(variables.myArrayList[i],"~",",","all");
  } 
</cfscript>
```

Comment: If you're unsure of the values or they are user-defined, then a tilde is just as bad. A colleague of mine would come up with the most ridiculous delimiters like <(|)> to deal with ColdFusions stupid lists.

Answer (score 9):

Actually there *is* a way to retrieve the data as an array. If your enctype is application/x-www-form-urlencoded (the default enctype) then you only need one line:

```
<cfset myArray = getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterValues('my_form_or_url_field_name')>
```

If your enctype is multipart/form-data (this is the type you use when uploading files) then things are a little more complicated. Here is a function I wrote that will return form & url values with a given name as an array, for either enctype:

```
<cffunction name="FormFieldAsArray" returntype="array" output="false" hint="Returns a Form/URL variable as an array.">
    <cfargument name="fieldName" required="true" type="string" hint="Name of the Form or URL field" />

    <cfset var tmpPartsArray = Form.getPartsArray() />
    <cfset var returnArray = arrayNew(1) /> 
    <cfset var tmpPart = 0 />
    <cfset var tmpValueArray = "" >

    <!--- if the getPartsArray method did not return NULL, then this is a multipart/form-data request, which must be handled as such. --->
    <cfif IsDefined("tmpPartsArray")>
        <cfloop array="#tmpPartsArray#" index="tmpPart">
            <cfif tmpPart.isParam() AND tmpPart.getName() EQ arguments.fieldName>
                <cfset arrayAppend(returnArray, tmpPart.getStringValue()) />
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>

    <!--- Add the values that maybe on the URL with the same name, also if this *wasn't* a multipart/form-data request then
    the above code did not get any of the data, and the method below will return all of it. --->
    <cfset tmpValueArray = getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterValues(arguments.fieldName) />

    <!--- that may have returned null, so need to test for it. --->
    <cfif IsDefined("tmpValueArray")>
        <cfloop array="#tmpValueArray#" index="tmpPart">
            <cfset arrayAppend(returnArray, tmpPart) />
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn returnArray />
</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 1):

A delimiter (in this case a comma) should *not* be present within the data, because then it is near impossible to identify where one element begins and another ends. The best solution is to use something else for the checkbox `value`. For example, if the descriptions are from a database table, use the numeric record ID instead of the long text description. Then this would be a non-issue.

Comment: You're right, but that assumes that it comes from a database in the first place. There are still many situations where one needs to input a list of things containing commas.

Comment: Yes, but you could still work around it by assigning a temporary numeric value. Then using the numeric value instead. Not quite as elegant as using a database ID ;) But similar concept.